# Skype for Business is not allowing me to contact external contact "due to company policy"

Tags: skype-for-business

So, I have a Skype for business account which doesn't allow me to IM or Call external contacts "due to company policy"

So upon login into to Office365 > Admin Centres > Skype for Business > Organisation > External Communications

I have set this to "On except for blocked domains" with no blocked domains set. You would have thought that logic would dictate that you should now be able to communicate with any anyone in the world who has a Skype account. Correct?

The result is, I still get the "This message wasn't sent to xxx due to company policy." message

This was the instructions I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/SkypeForBusiness/set-up-skype-for-business-online/allow-users-to-contact-external-skype-for-business-users?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

Also, I waited the required 24 hours as instructed - which resulted in a pointless exercise.

Can anyone point out anything I've missed or overlooked, or has anyone had the same issue and how did they resolved it?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue.

The secret for me was setting up the DNS for Skype for Business in the Office 365 admin center.

After I did this the message changed to "This message wasn't sent to xxx."

[image: Skype for Business with error message "This message wasn't sent to xxx"]

However, after about 2 days I was able to contact external contacts successfully via Skype for Business.